# Site showing up multiple times in Google search

Tags: wordpress, search, meta-tags

i have an odd request from someone to help them NOT have their site listed multiple times in google search results.

this is the query:
http://www.google.com/search?q=colwell+shelor

in bing and yahoo, it works as they desire, just the index page. but on google, i am getting each page listed separately.

does anyone have any insight as to what i could do to change this?

their site is a mix of wordpress and custom php with some of the meta and titles generated differently, but i am not sure that matters.

thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, that is a very good thing to get multiple listing on Google. People paid SEO optimizer to dominate all spots.

In order to prevent that you can make a robots.txt and stop google bot from crawling particular links on your site. However, if that is too extreme then you have to register an account at Google Webmaster Tool in order to change how your site will display on search engine.

www.google.com/webmasters/tools/

Comment: i believe it has to do with wp adding <link rel='prev' and  <link rel='next'

only pages with links to them in this way show up.

Comment: Well in a way it does. Your internal link structure/interlinked between those pages are what gives those page top ranking in google. Additionally, your search query is very unique, and Google just try its best to give the most relevance site all the traffics.